# Add negative to credited invoices only

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL. I have created a query to pull out the total of purchase invoices we have created and I have `Union All` to the total of purchase credits we have created. The problem I am having is the credits don't show a minus in front of the amount. When I total the results up, the purchase invoices are adding to the credit instead of taking it away.

Is there a way I can get the credits to show negative and invoices to show positive? Please see my query below.

```sql
SELECT 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ID, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_DATE, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_NUMBER, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_NETAMOUNT, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_GROSSAMOUNT, 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT, 
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE 
FROM 
  T_PURCHASEINVOICE (NOLOCK) 
  JOIN T_PURCHASEINVOICE_TAXLINE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_ID = T_PURCHASEINVOICE_TAXLINE.C__OWNER_ 
  JOIN T_TAXRATE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASEINVOICE_TAXLINE.C_TAXRATE = T_TAXRATE.C_ID 
WHERE 
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE = '01' 
  AND T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_TAXAMOUNT <> 0 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_ID, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_DATE, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NUMBER, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NETAMOUNT, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_GROSSAMOUNT, 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_TAXAMOUNT, 
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE 
FROM 
  T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE (NOLOCK) 
  JOIN T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE_TAXLINE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_ID = T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE_TAXLINE.C__OWNER_ 
  JOIN T_TAXRATE (NOLOCK) ON T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE_TAXLINE.C_TAXRATE = T_TAXRATE.C_ID 
WHERE 
  T_TAXRATE.C_CODE = '01'
```

This is the result

[image]

And this is the result I would like to see

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: perhaps value * -1

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Magnus sorry to be a bit thick but where would i put *-1?

Comment: how do you understand whether the amount is negative or positive?

Comment: From the C_Number column if its a PIN its positive if its PCN it will be negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a case statement in front of the following statement

```
T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_NETAMOUNT,
```

with

```
case when T_PURCHASECREDITNOTE.C_NUMBER  = 'PIN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * T_PURCHASEINVOICE.C_NETAMOUNT
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please consider to accept is as an answer so that community can benefit from it

Comment: worked perfectly thank you @Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu much appreciated! would you be able to up score me if possible? i would like my rep a little higher haha